# get Dimensions of Image (ReactNative)

Tags: react-native

I am having a weird issue... let me explain.

I have made an imageslider, the images are rendered via Flatlist like this:

```
<FlatList 
    horizontal = {true}
    data = {Slides}renderItem = {({item}) => 
    <Pressable 
    onPress = {() => {pressHandler(item)}}
    >
      <SlideItem item = {item}/>
    </Pressable>}
```

the purpose is that I want to display an image fullscreen when I click on it. And I need the dimensions of the image for that, that's why I have the Pressable.

```
function pressHandler(item) {
Image.getSize(item,(w, h) => {
    setHxw([h,w]);
})
console.log('hxw is ', hxw);
...
```

This is when it getting weird. When I press the image, Hxw (height x width) doesnt get updated, the array stays empty. But when I click it a second time, it gets updated with the correct data.
Why is this happening? Why I always have to click 2 times on a picture to get the dimensions?

what I already tried to do:

- running the Image.GetSize 2 times after each other
- putting the getsize in a function (and call it two times)
- when I console.log(w,h) before the setHxw, it gives me the right values. But I still need to click 2 times on the picture for Hxw being filled with [h,w]. First click, it still is [], only at the 2nd click it gives [h,w].
- putting everything in SLideItem. But same result, I have to click twice.
- making it an async function. Still same end result.
  ...
  whatever I try, it always gives the same result, I have to click the image 2 times before I get the dimensions.

what am I doing wrong?

Thx,
Peter

edit: `const [hxw, setHxw] = useState([]);`